# Empty table when creates materialized postgre in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

i am trying to make materilized postgre in clickhouse with the following command, the reply from clickhouse says it created the database successfully, but it returns an empty table whereas documenting when creating materialized postgres it will return the existing table, what should i do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnqLJ.png

Answer (score 1):

when creating the database, ClickHouse doesn't check on creation if the settings for MaterializedPostgreSQL engine are valid, it just creates the database to link.
for example, i can use something like this and creates the database on the clickhouse side:

```
CREATE DATABASE db3_postgres
ENGINE = MaterializedPostgreSQL('marsdb4.marsnet.local:5432', 'db1', 'clickhouse_user', 'wrong_password')
SETTINGS materialized_postgresql_tables_list = 'table1'

Query id: 7ab47c6a-fa1a-4f17-877e-f711a435c09e

Ok.

SHOW TABLES FROM db3_postgres

Query id: 412c6782-9ff2-4b50-a07e-563965bfe0b2

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec.
```

However, it won't use the settings until an operation is performed such as `show tables from db3_postgres` or query to the table.

check the logs for errors like this:

```
2022.08.22 22:40:52.726374 [ 566777 ] {} <Error> DatabaseMaterializedPostgreSQL (db3_postgres): Unable to load replicated tables list
2022.08.22 22:38:34.697116 [ 566834 ] {} <Error> void DB::DatabaseMaterializedPostgreSQL::startSynchronization(): std::exception. Code: 1001, type: pqxx::broken_connection, e.what() = connection to server at "marsdb4.marsnet.local" (192.168.1.248), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "clickhouse_user"
2022.08.22 22:40:52.726274 [ 566777 ] {} <Error> void DB::DatabaseMaterializedPostgreSQL::startSynchronization(): std::exception. Code: 1001, type: pqxx::broken_connection, e.what() = connection to server at "marsdb4.marsnet.local" (192.168.1.248), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "clickhouse_user"
```

ensure that the credentials are correct and that the auth method is set to `password`.
see this guide for simple reproducible steps for both Postgres side and CLickHouse side set up.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/postgresql/postgres-with-clickhouse-database-engine

Comment: and now it solved, but i got new issue. When the database created, it should return 299 rows table but its only return 57 rows tables, what should i do?

Comment: are the 57 rows new? or were there only 57 rows when the ClickHouse table was defined?